Find minimal polynomial of a matrix with $a_{ij} = a$ for every $a_{ij}$
I want to find the minimal polynomial of the following matrix:
$A = (a_{ij})\in M_n(K) $ with $ a_{ij} = a \not = 0$ for every i and j
I found the matrix diagonalizable as dim ImA = 1 and the matrix is not nilpotent, which implies that it is diagonalizable because of this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3479804/1286043
However, I have no idea how to get the minimal polynomial of the matrix.
How can I find it?
PS.:
Consider K a field with characteristic 0

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you want to get the minimal polynomial for which matrix? please clarify

Put the problem in the post,  not just the title. That depends on the characteristic of $K$. The kernel has dimension $n-1$, and $(1,\ldots,1)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $na$. If the characteristic of $K$ divides $n$, then the matrix is not diagonalizable. Otherwise, assuming $a\neq 0$, it is. The minimal polynomial equals $x(x-na)$.

@AnCar yes, I want to find the minimal polynomial, I edited the question, sorry for the confusion.

@ArturoMagidin, I get why the x-na is part of the minimal polynomial, but why the x is there?

Because $0$ is also an eigenvalue.

@ArturoMagidin about including the hypothesis just fixed it

I will leave the $n=1$ case to you. Assume $n\gt 1$.
If $a\neq 0$, the rank is $1$, so $0$ is an eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity $n-1$. The trace is $na$, so the remaining eigenvalue is $na$.
If $na\neq 0$ in $K$, then that means the matrix is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $0$ (multiplicity $n-1$) and $na$ (multiplicity $1$), so the minimal polynomial is $x(x-na)$.
If $na=0$ in $K$, which happens when $\text{char}K\mid n$, then the eigenvalue $0$ has algebraic multiplicity $n$ and geometric multiplicity $n-1$, so the matrix is not diagonalizable. The Jordan form has at least $n-1$ blocks, so the largest block has size at most $2$. So if the matrix is not diagonalizable, then the minimal polynomial must be $x^2$. But over $K$, this equals $x(x-na)$. So regardless of the characteristic of $K$, the minimal polynomial is $x(x-na)$.
Is $a=0$, the matrix is the zero matrix with minimal polynomial $x$.

If your matrix $A$ has the same value in each entry, call it $a$, then what are the possible eigenvalue-eigenvector pairs for it? If $v=(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)$, note that $Av=\lambda v$ implies $a\sum_{j=1}^n v_j = \lambda v_k$ for each $1\leq k\leq n$.
Now we have two cases.
Case 1: $\lambda\neq 0$. This quickly implies that $v_1=v_2=\dots=v_n$ and that $\lambda =na$. The 'only' eigenvector for this will be (up to scaling) $(1,1,\dots,1)$.
Case 2: $\lambda=0$. Here the only restriction we have is that $v_1+v_2+\dots+v_n=0$. The solutions form an $n-1$ dimensional subspace and we can take for eigenvectors, for example $(1,-1,0,0,\dots,0)$, $(1,0,-1,0,\dots,0)$ and so on and finally $(1,0,0,0,\dots,-1)$.
We see that we have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, so they form a basis, which means the matrix is diagonalizable. Since the only eigenvalues are $0$ and $na$, the characteristic poly is $x^{n-1}(x-na)$. But since the matrix is diagonalizable, the minimal poly can only have linear factors, so the minimal poly is $x(x-na)$.

It is not diagonalizable when $na=0$.

Indeed, I did not consider the possibility of the characteristic of the field being finite. Your answer covers that nicely. I kept my answer up because it also constructs the explicit eigenvectors in the usual cases $\mathbb K=\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb K = \mathbb R$.
